# My MySQL indexes are efficient?

Tags: mysql, indexing, innodb

I have following table:

```
mysql> describe as_rilevazioni;
+----------------------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                      | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                         | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| id_sistema_di_monitoraggio | longtext | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| id_unita                   | longtext | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| id_sensore                 | longtext | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| data                       | datetime | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| timestamp                  | longtext | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| unita_di_misura            | longtext | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| misura                     | longtext | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I have following indexes on my table:

```
mysql> show indexes from as_rilevazioni;
+----------------+------------+----------+--------------+----------------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table          | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name                | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+----------------+------------+----------+--------------+----------------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| as_rilevazioni |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | id                         | A         |   315865898 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| as_rilevazioni |          0 | UNIQUE   |            1 | id_sistema_di_monitoraggio | A         |          17 |        5 | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| as_rilevazioni |          0 | UNIQUE   |            2 | id_unita                   | A         |          17 |       10 | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| as_rilevazioni |          0 | UNIQUE   |            3 | id_sensore                 | A         |      145225 |       30 | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| as_rilevazioni |          0 | UNIQUE   |            4 | data                       | A         |   315865898 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+----------------+------------+----------+--------------+----------------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
5 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

I am afraid these indexes are not efficient because the cardinality of index based on column "data" is as large as the number of records data!
These indexes speed up my queries or it take a lot of space without benefits?

This is the table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `as_rilevazioni` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_sistema_di_monitoraggio` longtext NOT NULL,
  `id_unita` longtext NOT NULL,
  `id_sensore` longtext NOT NULL,
  `data` datetime NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` longtext NOT NULL,
  `unita_di_misura` longtext NOT NULL,
  `misura` longtext NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNIQUE` (`id_sistema_di_monitoraggio`(5),`id_unita`(10),`id_sensore`(30),`data`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=437497044 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

The main query that I use is:

```
select * from as_rilevazioni where id_sistema_di_monitoraggio="<value>" and id_unita="<value>" and id_sensore="<value>" and data>="<date_1>" and data<="<date2>"
```

This is the query explained:

```
mysql> explain select * from as_rilevazioni where id_sistema_di_monitoraggio="235" and id_unita="17" and id_sensore="15" and data >= "2015-01-01 00:00:00" order by data;
+----+-------------+----------------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table          | type  | possible_keys | key    | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+----------------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | as_rilevazioni | range | UNIQUE        | UNIQUE | 59      | NULL | 285522 | Using where |
+----+-------------+----------------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

This is the dimension of data and indexes:

```
mysql> SELECT concat(table_schema,'.',table_name) tables,
    ->        concat(round(table_rows/1000000,2),'M') rows,
    ->        concat(round(data_length/(1024*1024*1024),2),'G') data_size,
    ->        concat(round(index_length/(1024*1024*1024),2),'G') index_size,
    ->        concat(round((data_length+index_length)/(1024*1024*1024),2),'G') total_size,
    ->        round(index_length/data_length,2) index_data_ratio
    -> FROM information_schema.TABLES
    -> WHERE table_name="as_rilevazioni"
    -> ORDER BY total_size DESC;
+------------------------------------+---------+-----------+------------+------------+------------------+
| tables                             | rows    | data_size | index_size | total_size | index_data_ratio |
+------------------------------------+---------+-----------+------------+------------+------------------+
| agriculturalsupport.as_rilevazioni | 317.12M | 19.06G    | 10.25G     | 29.31G     |             0.54 |
+------------------------------------+---------+-----------+------------+------------+------------------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks to all!

Comment: I can't understand what you want. Possible answers to your question - `yes` or `no`. Look like everything done correct, so, my answer is `yes`. But, only one way to answer your question will be result of `explain` sql execution. Please do `explain select ... ` and check data inside of `extra` column. If there is only `using index` it's perfect. If there is no `using index`, look like your indexes does not work.

Comment: Try to add a [multiple-column index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) on `id_sistema_di_monitoraggio`, `id_unita`, `id_sensore` and `data`.

Comment: There is already a multiple-column index.
I add the explain of the query in the original message.

Answer (score 0):

```
UNIQUE a(5), b(10)
```

is terrible.  It is saying to check for uniqueness of only the first 5 bytes of `a` together with the first 10 bytes of `b`.  You probably wanted to check the combination of the full `a` and `b` for uniqueness.

```
INDEX a(5), b(10)
```

is virtually useless -- it will not get past `a` to even consider `b`.

```
INDEX a(5)
```

is sometimes useless.

```
UNIQUE a, data  -- where `data` is `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`
```

is usually "wrong".  Are you really sure that the `a` cannot show up twice in one second?

"Cardinality" is often unimportant when looking at multi-column indexes.  A cardinality that is equal to the *estimated* number of rows in the table means that it *thinks* that the column is unique; but it won't count on it.

By "efficient", do you mean "does not take 'too much' space"?  Each 'row' of your `UNIQUE` index will take about 1+5 + 1+10 + 1+30 + 5 = 53 bytes.  Multiple that by 317M and you get 17GB.  Add about 40% for overhead to get 23GB.  That is a lot more than the 10GB in information_schema.  (The error involves many approximations -- probably mostly the number of rows.)

Or, do you mean "this index speeds up some query"?  To discuss that, we need to see the query.  (Meanwhile, I have pointed out several reasons why the index is bad.)

**If the IDs are numbers**

If they really are numeric, then switch to `SMALLINT UNSIGNED` (2 bytes) or some other size.  *Then* an index with those 4 columns (and `data` *last*) is very likely to speed up that query significantly.  Yes, the index will cost some disk space, but it will *probably* be worth it.  `TEXT`, with "prefixing", simply will not provide efficiency.

Also indexing numbers is cheaper than strings.  Your `id_unita(10)` takes up to 11 bytes in each row in the index; `MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED` takes a fixed 3 bytes.  That is, the index will be smaller *and* more useful.

Comment: With "efficient" I mean "this index speeds up my query? or it takes a lot of space for without benefits?" :)

The query is:

`select * from as_rilevazioni where id_sistema_di_monitoraggio="235" and id_unita="17" and id_sensore="15" and data >= "2015-01-01 00:00:00" order by data;`

Comment: see my addition.